# Using IPA symbols in a table with Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle11g, internationalization, phonetics

I am working in a project which will make use of IPA symbols in some tables and Oracle 11g, and I want to know if these symbols are supported and if I should take some precautions when creating the database, schema and tables.

By the way I am new to Oracle 11g but it is compulsory for to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "IPA symbols" refers to the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/), those characters should all be available in the Unicode character set.  When you create your database, you'll need to ensure that you are using a Unicode character set (AL32UTF8).  And you'll need to ensure that your application supports Unicode.